# C/C++ cross-platform compilation

Tags: c++, compilation

How do I make my program cross-platform? I understand that each operating system has their own API calls and you would use #ifdef, but I don't understand how you can make it compilable on each platform. For instance Linux uses Makefile but I don't think Windows or Mac does. I was recommended qmake and cmake, but it doesn't seem to be widely used in github projects. I usually see them having ./configure and a Makefile instead. Two projects that pique my curiosity on how they're cross-platform are VLC and ffmpeg.

Comment: You may want to look at CMake which generates projects for many different os / compiler / ides from a CMakeLists.txt file that you create.

Comment: Cmake, Makefiles, etc. are irrelevant. I think you'd be more concerned with using libraries that are cross platform and not specific to Windows, Mac, etc. Cmake can make that easier, but it's not CMake that makes it cross platform.

Comment: But I notice other projects do not use CMake. Why is that?

Comment: You may want to look into Cygwin: https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: That doesn't make it cross-platform for things such as Android or Mac though.

Comment: Most compilers have a command line version.  The command line version is used when building cross-platform.  You will need to open a terminal or console window and run CMake or other building utility.

Comment: Why do popular projects like VLC or ffmpeg not use CMake?

Comment: because cmake is new and vlc, ffmpeg are old

Comment: At the same I just read an announcement that CMake hit its 15th birthday recently. Although I agree it was not popular until recently.